# CUDA parallelizing work with arrays

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, cuda

I am new in CUDA, i have just read some NVIDIA tutors about CUDA and i need some help. There is the following code:

```
//some includes
#define NUM_OF_ACCOMS 3360
#define SIZE_RING 16
#define NUM_OF_BIGRAMMS 256

//...some code...
    for (i = 1; i <= SIZE_RING; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= SIZE_RING; j++) {
            if (j == i) continue;
            for (k = 1; k <= SIZE_RING; k++) {
                if (k == j || k == i) continue;
                accoms_theta[indOfAccoms][0] = i - 1; accoms_theta[indOfAccoms][1] = j - 1; accoms_theta[indOfAccoms][2] = k - 1;
                accoms_thetaFix[indOfAccoms][0] = i - 1; accoms_thetaFix[indOfAccoms][1] = j - 1; accoms_thetaFix[indOfAccoms][2] = k - 1;
                results[indOfAccoms][0] = results[indOfAccoms][1] = results[indOfAccoms][2] = 0;
                indOfAccoms++;
            }
        }
    }   

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE_RING; j++) {
            bigramms[indOfBigramms][0] = i; bigramms[indOfBigramms][1] = j;
            indOfBigramms++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ACCOMS; i++) {
            thetaArr[0] = accoms_theta[i][0]; thetaArr[1] = accoms_theta[i][1]; thetaArr[2] = accoms_theta[i][2];
            d0 = thetaArr[2] - thetaArr[1]; d1 = thetaArr[2] - thetaArr[0];
            if (d0 < 0)
                d0 += SIZE_RING;
            if (d1 < 0)
                d1 += SIZE_RING;
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ACCOMS; j++) {
                theta_fixArr[0] = accoms_thetaFix[j][0]; theta_fixArr[1] = accoms_thetaFix[j][1]; theta_fixArr[2] = accoms_thetaFix[j][2];
                d0_fix = theta_fixArr[2] - theta_fixArr[1]; d1_fix = theta_fixArr[2] - theta_fixArr[0];
                count = 0;
                if (d0_fix < 0)
                    d0_fix += SIZE_RING;
                if (d1_fix < 0)
                    d1_fix += SIZE_RING;
                for (k = 0; k < NUM_OF_BIGRAMMS; k++) {
                    diff0 = subst[(d0 + bigramms[k][0]) % SIZE_RING] - subst[bigramms[k][0]];
                    diff1 = subst[(d1 + bigramms[k][1]) % SIZE_RING] - subst[bigramms[k][1]];

                    if (diff0 < 0)
                        diff0 += SIZE_RING;
                    if (diff1 < 0)
                        diff1 += SIZE_RING;
                    if (diff0 == d0_fix && diff1 == d1_fix)
                        count++;
                }
                if (max < count) {
                    max = count;
                    results[indResults][0] = max; results[indResults][1] = i; results[indResults][2] = j;
                    count = 0;
                    indResults++;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, there are two main cycles with `i` and `j` variables. I need foreach array from `accoms_theta` check the condition with each array from `accoms_thetaFix`. (`subst` is an `int` array with SIZE_RING elements). Well you need for about `2^30` operations to check ALL arrays. Cause i am new in CUDA i need some help in parallelizing my algorithm.

Here is some info about my device

```
GeForce GT730M
Compute Capability 3.5
Global Memory 2 GB
Shared Memory Per Block 48 KB
Max Threads Per Block 1024
Number of multiprocessors 2
Max Threads Dim 1024 : 1024 : 64
Max Grid Dim 2*(10 ^ 9) : 65535 : 65535
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not go into the specific details of whatever it is you're trying to compute, but I will make a suggestion regarding what you might do.

A straightforward approach to parallelizing a serial algorithm in CUDA (or OpenCL, or OpenMP even) is to "parallelize for loops". In the context of CUDA that means instead of having a single thread iterate over values of some index `i`, you have different GPU threads work on the different values of `i` (or - one thread for every several values of `i`).

This can be done with nested loops, e.g. with two indices `i` and `j` corresponding to two dimensions of your kernel launch grid.

However - doing this 'naively' is only possible for [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems - where there are no dependencies between the data to be computed/written by each of the threads (e.g. for each combination of `i` and `j`). Also, if the data that's *read* for different `i` and `j` overlaps, or is interleaved, additional care is required to prevent reading the same data repeatedly, degrading performance.

Try this approach. If it fails, or if you reach the conclusion that it cannot apply, please ask another question - but in that question we will need a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - which you have not provided for this question.